# Leaflet for R clear raster with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shapes, raster

I'm wondering if their is a way to clear a raster image with shiny when the user click on some radio button. I saw there is a function to clear polygons -  `clearshape()` but I need to do the same with my raster image.

```
leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
             addRasterImage(r, colors=pal, opacity = 0.9, maxBytes = 123123123) %>%
             clearShapes()
```

This does not work...

Comment: I had to ask to find the answer just after. The function is clearImages().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearImages()` can be used to replace or remove rasters - https://rdrr.io/cran/leaflet/man/remove.html:

```
leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
             addRasterImage(r, colors=pal, opacity = 0.9, maxBytes = 123123123) %>%
             clearImages()
```